# Matching certain features of CAD-File and 2D-images

Tags: image, matching, feature-extraction, feature-detection, cad

whats the best way to start, for matching certain features of a CAD-File to 2D-images?

So basically it's about quality assurance in manufacturing:
There are CAD-files of an assembly, that show the finished state of the assembly.
At the end of the assembly line, I want to take an image of the finished part and then match certain features to the CAD-file (bolts for example).